# Job requirements. Why do they write words with capital letters within sentences?

Tags: grammar, sentence, capitalization, rules

I noticed the capitalization within sentences. For example,

> Great experience in Java, Android SDK with core knowledge of Object
> Oriented Programming principles and Design Patterns.

Is there a grammar rule explaining the capitalization?

**Update #1.**

Now we have the following opinions.

**@*Jim*** and **@*Sweet72***

> They're all proper names of things.
>
> The names of Proper nouns always begin with capital letters. Java, Android SDK, Object Oriented Programming, Design patterns ; all refer to proper nouns

**@*Xerxes***

> Neither "object-oriented programming" nor "design patterns" is a proper noun. The author of the piece merely means to emphasize these terms and does not know how to correctly do so.

***My opinion***

Android SDK and Java are proper names.

Object Oriented Programming, Design Patterns. I think employers just want to place emphasis on these key words. I may be wrong.

Comment: They're all proper names of things.

Comment: @Jim, I wish I could vote for your comment. Thanks.

Comment: @Jim : how it would be instead of writing answer in comment . You mention directly in the space given for the answer.

Comment: I even write JAVA and JavaScript and jQuery

Comment: `Is there a grammar rule explaining the capitalization?` No there's not!

Comment: There *can* be no grammar rule explaining the capitalization, because capitalization is *orthography*, not grammar. ThiS SEnteNCE is Grammatically iMpeccabLE.

Comment: Capitalized and uncapitalized phrases can mean **entirely** different things, as in 'Design Patterns & 'Design patterns'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as *Java* and *Android SDK* are concerned, they're proper nouns.

*Object-oriented programming* is often written as OOP. Perhaps the author of the sentence thought it should be capitalised because the abbreviated form OOP has capitalised letters. The proper way of writing it would be 'object-oriented programming', since it is in the middle of a sentence.

*Design patterns* should not have capitalised letters - it isn't a proper noun, neither does it have an abbreviation; the author may have capitalised it for emphasis. Or he just isn't familiar with the rules of this language that well!

Comment: You're exactly right. You can look at the job ads here and very few have errant capitalization: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/tag/description The Computer industry has a huge number of people from overseas who may not know all the fine points of English grammar. Even people born here often have major problems.

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought. :) It isn't necessary that the person who wrote this is an English expert. He may have written "I Looking for great person"; that doesn't mean there are rules supporting what he's written. cc: @RedPlanet :)

Comment: _Design Patterns_ was originally the title of a book, but it isn't usually referred to like that. Plus it would need italics.

Comment: @BraddSzonye I don't think the writer is referring to a book - he would have clarified it further. Plus 'design pattern' is a concept which is likely what the writer was referring to. Unless this is some *really* popular book I do not know about :)

Comment: I believe it's the book that originated the concept in software engineering – it _was_ very popular when it was published in the 1990s. I agree, however, that it's not used as a proper noun here.